# WPF Control Template not being applied to first item rendered

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

I'm building a WPF application and I have a control template defined in App.XAML for a combobox.

When I start the application, the first combo box that is rendered does not use the style defined in the control template while all other do. Also, the first combo box that I open has an unstyled first item while the rest of the items in that combo box and others are styled.

What am I missing?

Here's the app.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfPropertyGrid_Demo.App"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

                            <ResourceDictionary>
                                <!--Brushes defined here-->
                            </ResourceDictionary>


                            <ResourceDictionary>
                                <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Border
                                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                            Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" />
                                            <Border 
                                                x:Name="Border" 
                                                Grid.Column="1"
                                                Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" />
                                                <Path 
                                                    x:Name="Arrow"
                                                    Grid.Column="1"     
                                                    Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                    Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ActiveBrush}" />
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ActiveBrush}" />
                                                        <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource ActiveGlyphBrush}" />
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                        <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            </ControlTemplate>

                                            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
                                                <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                                            </ControlTemplate>

                                            <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="ComboBox">
                                                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                                                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
                                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
                                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
                                                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                                                            <Grid>
                                                                <ToggleButton 
                                                                    Name="ToggleButton" 
                                                                    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                                                                    Grid.Column="2" 
                                                                    Focusable="false"
                                                                    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                                    ClickMode="Press">
                                                                </ToggleButton>
                                                                <ContentPresenter
                                                                    Name="ContentSite"
                                                                    IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                                                                    Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                                                    ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                                                    Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                                                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                                                        Style="{x:Null}" 
                                                                        Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                                        Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                                                        Focusable="True" 
                                                                        Background="Transparent"
                                                                        Visibility="Hidden"
                                                                        IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                                                                        <Popup 
                                                                            Name="Popup"
                                                                            Placement="Bottom"
                                                                            IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                                                                            AllowsTransparency="True" 
                                                                            Focusable="False"
                                                                            PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                                                            <Grid 
                                                                                Name="DropDown"
                                                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                                                                                MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                                                                MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                                                                <Border 
                                                                                    x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                                                                    Background="{StaticResource ActiveBrush}" />
                                                                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="4,4,4,4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                                                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                                                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                                                                </Grid>
                                                                            </Popup>
                                                                        </Grid>
                                                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                                                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                                                                            </Trigger>
                                                                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                                            </Trigger>
                                                                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                                                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                                                                            </Trigger>
                                                                            <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
                                                                                Value="true">
                                                                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                                                                                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                                                            </Trigger>
                                                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                                        </Style>

                                                        <!-- SimpleStyles: ComboBoxItem -->
                                                        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                                                            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                                                                        <Border Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                                                            <ContentPresenter />
                                                                        </Border>
                                                                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                                                                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                                                            </Trigger>
                                                                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                                                                            </Trigger>
                                                                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
                                                                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ActiveGlyphBrush}"/>
                                                                            </Trigger>
                                                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                                </Setter.Value>
                                                            </Setter>
                                                        </Style>
                                                    </ResourceDictionary>

                                                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                                            </ResourceDictionary>
                                        </Application.Resources>
                                    </Application>
```

Here's the actual window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfPropertyGrid_Demo.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:wpg="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls"
Title="WpfPropertyGrid Demo" mc:Ignorable="d" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" 
Width="360" Height="360" MinWidth="360" MinHeight="400">

<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="SortTypes" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="wpg:PropertySort"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Margin="0,20,12,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ComboBox Name="ComboSort" Margin="0,3,0,0" Width="95" FontSize="10"
            SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortTypes}}" />
        <ComboBox Name="ComboSort2" Margin="0,3,0,0" Width="95" FontSize="10"
            SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortTypes}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you show some XAML ?

Comment: Sorry, I slipped my mind. The app.xaml is in now

Comment: That looks okay, because it does applied on rest of your ComboBox controls so don't think if ControlTemplate has any issue. Please show the XAML where you are creating ComboBox controls.

Comment: I've added the window xaml

Comment: Strange!. Please try putting your ComboBox style in a separate ResourceDictionary, let say ComboBox.xaml and merge this ComboBox.xaml to the App.xaml under  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> tag.

Comment: Awesome! That worked. If you stick it in an answer I will mark it as answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please put your `ComboBox` style in a separate `ResourceDictionary`, let say ComboBox.xaml and merge this ComboBox.xaml to the App.xaml.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ComboBox.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I would suggest to create a separate `ResourceDictionary` for every control you create your own Template. This way it would be easy to manage your resources.